# MergeAdapter with Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, commonsware-cwac

**Libraries:**

- https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge
- https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView
- https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

I'd like to add a gridview adapter with MergeAdapter.

**1st way, If you set adapter:**

```
plv = (PullToRefreshListView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_listview_in_viewpager, container, false);
adapter = new MergeAdapter();
sadapter = new StaggeredAdapter(BaseSampleActivity.this, R.id.imageView1, urls);
adapter.addAdapter(sadapter);
plv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then it works like a list view.

**2nd way, if you build a view:**

```
plv = (PullToRefreshListView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_listview_in_viewpager, container, false);
adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addView(buildlabel3(context));
plv.setAdapter(adapter);

public View buildlabel3(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) v.findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);

        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);

        gridView.setItemMargin(margin); // set the GridView margin
        gridView.setPadding(margin, 0, margin, 0); // have the margin on the sides as well 

        StaggeredAdapter sadapter = new StaggeredAdapter(BaseSampleActivity.this, R.id.imageView1, urls);

        gridView.setAdapter(sadapter);
        sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("view", v.toString());
        return v;
    }
```

Then it doesn't show anything and with no error.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean with "it doesn't show anything." Does the new StaggeredGridView not show up, or does the original view also disappear? Is the screen completely blank?

Comment: It dont build the view, so the view don't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addView()` on `MergeAdapter` is designed for `ListView` headers and the like. You, instead, are attempting to put a `GridView` as an element inside of some other `AdapterView` that is using the `MergeAdapter`. That is not supported by `MergeAdapter`, and putting a `GridView` inside of another `AdapterView` is unlikely to work no matter how you try to do it.

Also, I do not recommend making an `Adapter` be `static`, and *certainly* not a `MergeAdapter`, as it would represent a significant memory leak (and is unnecessary in the first place).

Comment: So you mean that is impossible to put mergeAdapter to work with grid view or that I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @Marckaraujo: The way to use `MergeAdapter` with a `GridView` would be to call `setAdapter()` on the `GridView`, passing in the `MergeAdapter`. I have not tried this, but I seem to recall that others have and that it works. However, that is not what you are doing in your second block of code.

Comment: I understand now, the problem that I used setAdapter() on the PullToRefreshListView, passing in the MergeAdapter. So I build some views with mergeAdapter and after set it to PullToRefreshListView.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is very generic. As in your code

```
private static MergeAdapter adapter = null;
adapter.addView(buildlabel3(context));
```

adapter is null, and not initialised. So whatever you add to it, it still null.

I have seen the soucre code of MergeAdapter. It has a constructor:

```
public MergeAdapter() {
    super();
}
```

So just change your code to

```
private static MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addView(buildlabel3(context));
```

and then try again.

Comment: No, man. I know it, I just cropped my code with few information to focus on the problem. In my original code, I do adapter = new MergeAdapter();, thx anyway