# Scrolling Infinitely in android Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i want to do infinite scrolling in gridview that means my scrolling in gridview never stops. it can scroll infinitely. if the scroll ends then it repeats from the first record.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to show what you have already done.

You can do infinite scroll with `MergeAdapter(CWAC)`

But merge adapter and GridView is not a good idea.

Have you seen this link: [MergeAdapter with Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197626/mergeadapter-with-gridview)?