# Lazy load of Youtube Thumbnail in Grid view in android using youtube api

Tags: android, gridview, video, youtube-api, lazy-loading

I am developing an android app, which shows a grid view of Youtube Thumbnail and when click on a Thumbnail , play the video. I have successfully done this part.
But my video list is huge , I do not want to load all the Thumbnail at a time, I want to load more Thumbnail when user reach at the end of primary Thumbnail list.

I am using youtube api .
Please help me,

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100086/scrolling-infinitely-in-android-gridview

Comment: sorry, but i look over your link, but it is not clear for me